# Xamarin file saving problems

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on an Xamarins.Forms cross platform social media app.

When a user logs in I save their Session which is grabbed from a database.

When a user pushes login I run the following line, the page_result it the session and I know its not null I have checked.

```
FileUtils.UpdateSession(page_result)
```

Here is my FileUtils class (Not my work found from tutorial)

```
public async static Task<IFile> CreateFile(this string filename, IFolder rootFolder = null)
    {
        IFolder folder = rootFolder ?? FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
        IFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        return file;
    }
    public async static Task<bool> WriteTextAllAsync(this string filename, string content = "", IFolder rootFolder = null)
    {
        IFile file = await filename.CreateFile(rootFolder);
        await file.WriteAllTextAsync(content);
        return true;
    }

    public async static Task<string> ReadAllTextAsync(this string fileName, IFolder rootFolder = null)
    {
        string content = "";
        IFolder folder = rootFolder ?? FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
        bool exist = await fileName.IsFileExistAsync(folder);
        if (exist == true)
        {
            IFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
            content = await file.ReadAllTextAsync();
        }
        return content;
    }
    public async static Task<bool> DeleteFile(this string fileName, IFolder rootFolder = null)
    {
        IFolder folder = rootFolder ?? FileSystem.Current.LocalStorage;
        bool exist = await fileName.IsFileExistAsync(folder);
        if (exist == true)
        {
            IFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
            await file.DeleteAsync();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Then I added this to add support for what I needed

```
public async static Task<bool> UpdateSession(this string sessionID)
    {
        await CreateFile("session");
        await WriteTextAllAsync("session", sessionID);
        return true;
    }

    public async static Task<string> GetSession()
    {
        IFolder folder = await GetFolder("session");
        return await ReadAllTextAsync("session", folder);
    }

    public async static Task LogoutSession()
    {
        IFolder folder = await GetFolder("session");
        await DeleteFile("session", folder);
    }
```

When I push the login button first it is extremely slow takes about 2 minutes to do anything, I can't have it take that long is there something I'm doing wrong? Also it crashes after the 2 minutes and says the stacktrace was printed to '/data/anr/traces.txt' but I am not able to find it.

Comment: which method is called when the user clicks login?  Have you used the debugger to trace the execution?  Have you tried using try/catch blocks to catch any exceptions?

Comment: @Jason When the user clicks login it calls the UpdateSession(session)

Comment: OK, what about my other two suggestions?  Fundamentally, you need to catch whatever exception is occurring so you can determine what the root cause is

Comment: @Jason I tried adding a try and catch, it didn't print any exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using MySql instead.